# Where is the 2nd thread in the race condition?

Tags: java, multithreading, race-condition

The following example is from a book explaining Race conditions. The example says that it has 2 threads. I can only see 1 thread implemented i.e. `Thread lo = new Race0();`. Can someone please help me understand the program? I am new to multi-threading environment.

Where is the first thread being invoked?

Race0:

```
class Race0 extends Thread {
    static Shared0 s;
    static volatile boolean done = false;
    public static void main(String[] x) {
        Thread lo = new Race0();
        s = new Shared0();
        try {
            lo.start();
            while (!done) {
                s.bump();
                sleep(30);
            }
            lo.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        }
    }
    public void run() {
        int i;
        try {
            for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                if (i % 60 == 0)
                    System.out.println();
                System.out.print(“.X”.charAt(s.dif()));
                sleep(20);
            }
            System.out.println();
            done = true;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Shared0:

```
class Shared0 {
    protected int x = 0, y = 0;
    public int dif() {
        return x - y;
    }
    public void bump() throws InterruptedException {
        x++;
        Thread.sleep(9);
        y++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thread is the main thread that the `main` method is running in, and the other thread is the thread that it instantiates and starts (`Thread lo = new Race0();`).

A java program starts with execuing the `main` method in the main thread.

This program creates a second thread, `lo`, starts the thread (by calling `lo.start();`), and runs a loop.

At this point the main thread is running the loop :

```
        while (!done) {
            s.bump();
            sleep(30);
        }
```

At the same time, the second thread, `lo`, is executing its `run` method :

```
    try {
        for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            if (i % 60 == 0)
                System.out.println();
            System.out.print(“.X”.charAt(s.dif()));
            sleep(20);
        }
        System.out.println();
        done = true;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Isnt the main thread program and the other thread `Thread lo = new Race0();` the same thread? can you please explain in detail. I did not understand.

Comment: @fscore -- Before `new Race0()` is executed there is only one thread -- the main thread.  After it's executed there are two.  A new thread was created.

Comment: How are both the threads running simultaneously? For the main method thread, I thought you have to use method `start()` for the thread to start executing. So if any program `extends Thread` and a instance of that program is created, a `start` method is invoked automatically?

Comment: What does `Thread lo = new Race()` mean as `lo.start()` is being invoked so that means both of them together are a thread so where did the main method thread go?

Comment: @fscore The fact that the main method runs in the main thread has nothing to do with the fact that Race0 extends Thread. The JVM creates a Thread for the main method to run in.

Comment: So that means, whenever any class extends a thread, JVM automatically creates a thread for it and whatever thread is being created inside the main or wherever in the class would be the 2nd thread. correct?

Comment: @fscore A Thread is a class that either implements the Runnable interface, which contains the run() method. When you create an instance of a Thread class (for example by calling `Thread lo = new Thread();`), you are not yet executing the thread. Only when you call the start() method, the new thread is created and executes the run () method. When a new thread is started, the thread from which it was started (in our case the main thread) continues to run in parallel.

Comment: @fscore No, this behavior is unrelated to whether the class extends Thread or not. JVM always creates and starts the main thread for any java program, and executes the main method in the main thread. Any method in any class can create new threads and start them, thus causing multiple threads to run in parallel.

Comment: So even if I remove `extend Thread` from the main program. The race condition would occur right?

Comment: @fscore If you remove `extend Thread` you wouldn't be able to initialize and start the second thread the way it is currently done, but you'll still be able to do it some other way. For example, by `Thread lo = new Thread (new Runnable (} {public void run(...)});` or by having the Race0 class implement Runnable and creating the thread with `Thread lo = new Thread (new Race0()).

Comment: thanks. That helps. But would you recommend any book/resource from wherever you learned all this? Esp Multi-threading

Comment: @fscore There are many books about concurrency in Java, but I haven't read any of them. I recommend to start with the Concurrency chapter of Bruce Eckel's Thinking in Java. Actually I suggest you read the entire book. It's very good. You can even download the older edition for free - just Google "java bruce eckel pdf". You'll see in the results a download link to the 4th edition.